# Is it possible to use libdshowcapture with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, screen-capture, directshow

libdshowcapture is OBS' directshow screen grabber library

Currently the ffmpeg dshow input also relies on 3rd party software (uscreencapture, sharex and possibly others)

The integrated screen capture for ffmpeg is gdigrab but there are performance limitation with using this method (higher cpu load, can't capture over 30 frames per second etc..)

Comment: Not currently implemented.

Comment: Yes, not implemented directly in ffmpeg but maybe there's software I've missed that wraps libdshowcapture and produces a dshow video device ?